# Getting 404 errors for codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

this is my class:

```
class Pacients extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $this->load->model('pacient_model');
        $this->load->model('department_model');
    }
    public function index(){
        $id_doctor = $this->session->userdata('userid');
        $department = $this->department_model->get_department_by_doctor($id_doctor); // get deparmentd_id
        $diagnostics = $this->department_model->get_diagnostics($department[0]->department_id); // get diagnostics by using deparment id 
        $department_data = $this->department_model->get_department_by_id($department[0]->department_id); // get all info about deparment

        //start pagination 
        if ($this->uri->segment(2) == null || $this->uri->segment(2) == ""){
            $limit = 0;
        }else{
            $limit = $this->uri->segment(2);
        }
        $get_pacients = $this->pacient_model->get_pacients_by_doctor($id_doctor, $limit);
        $total = $this->pacient_model->get_total_pacients_by_doctor($id_doctor);
        $config['base_url']   = base_url().'pacients';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total[0]->total;
        $config['per_page']   = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        // end pagination
        $data = array(
            'pacients'        => $get_pacients,
            'diagnostics'     => $diagnostics,
            'department_data' => $department_data
        ); 
        if (!$diagnostics){// check if there any diagnostic in db associated to the current department
            $data['error'] = 1;// if it is 1 then a form will apears in the view
        }

        $this->load->view('frontend/common/header');
        $this->load->view('frontend/pacients',$data);
        $this->load->view('frontend/common/footer');
    } 
}
```

In the get_pacients variable I have all of the results and I got all of the wanted results. in view in shows me the pagination. but when i clicked on the page 2 it shows me the 404 page.  It is weird, on another page i used the same pagination implementation and it works. The url looks like:

```
http://localhost/licenta/pacients
```

Do you have any idea why I get the 404 ? I am using Codeigniter 3. Thx in advance

Comment: can you show pacients view?

Comment: this is in the view: echo $this->pagination->create_links();

Comment: in codeigniter by default 2nd segment of the URI is method of class. so you have to change your pagination variable to `$this->uri->segment(3);` and base_url to  `$config['base_url']   = base_url().'pacients/index';` other wise codeigniter will try to load a method which is actually your pagination variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In codeigniter by default 2nd segment of the URI is method of class. so you have to change your pagination variable to you have to make these changes.

`$this->uri->segment(2);` to `$this->uri->segment(3);`

`$config['base_url'] = base_url().'pacients/index';`